# Writing to s3 from Spark EMR fails with UnsupportedStagingDirectoryOperationException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-emr

I'm trying to write a dataframe into s3 by doing.

```
(fl
    .write
    .partitionBy("XXX")
    .option('path', 's3://some/location')
    .bucketBy(40, "YY", "ZZ")
    .saveAsTable(f"DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME")

)
```

And i was seeing lots of smaller multipart parts and decided to disable multipart upload by doing:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.s3n.multipart.uploads.enabled", "false")
```

Now when I run the code, I get

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.staging.UnsupportedStagingDirectoryOperationException: Multipart uploads (fs.s3n.multipart.uploads.enabled) must be enabled in order to create files under a staging directory
```

I thought multi part was optional, what's going on with this?